# Redirect 301: how to convert from Nginx to Apache

Tags: regex, apache, nginx

I need to move a website from an Nginx web server to Apache. I managed to successfully convert everything but two rules needed for compatibility with legacy URLs (the website had been formerly developed in ASP then rewritten in PHP).

Such rules are:

```
location /images/index.asp {
    return 301 $scheme://$server_name/image-library?$args;
}
```

which redirects requests for https://www.domain.ext/images/index.asp?var1=somevalue&var2=someother to https://www.domain.ext/image-library?var1=somevalue&var2=someother

and:

```
location ~ ^/images/(?<year>[0-9]+)/index.asp {
    return 301 $scheme://$server_name/image-library?img_year=$year&$args;
}
```

which redirects requests for https://www.domain.ext/images/2018/index.asp?var1=somevalue&var2=someother to https://www.domain.ext/image-library?img_year=2018&var1=somevalue&var2=someother

Can you please help me writing the proper RedirectMatch 301 rules?

Comment: What have you tried?  See [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

...in the meantime i found out a solution that works for me: The first rule can be translated as:

```
RewriteRule ^/images/index.asp https://www.domain.ext/image-library [R=301,QSA]
```

and the second one as:

```
RewriteRule ^/images/([0-9]+)/index.asp https://www.domain.ext/image-library?img_year=$1 [R=301,QSA]
```